# WCF Problems Integrating with JSON

Tags: json, wcf

I am having problems calling my WCF service via jquery / JSON.

So far I have done the following:

1. In VS 2010, start a new "WCF Service Application" project. Visual Studio then auto generates a sample service called IService / Service, which has the function

   ```
   string GetData(int value);
   ```
2. Inside IService.cs I add the WebGet attribute, as follows:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   string GetData(int value);
   ```
3. Inside my web.config I have

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
     </system.web>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
         <service name="WcfService1.Service1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
           <endpoint contract="WcfService1.IService1"
                     binding="webHttpBinding"
                     behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" />
         </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
           </behavior>
           <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
             <enableWebScript />
           </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. I build and run the service, and on opening

   ```
   http://localhost:58403/Service1.svc/GetData?value=1
   ```

   in my web browser it prints out (as expected)

{"d":"You entered: 1"}

5, I create a new asp.net web application project. Inside default.aspx, I add

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:58403/Service1.svc/GetData",
                data: { value: "1" }
            });

            request.done(function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

6, I build and run that, but instead of hitting the done callback, it hits the error callback and alerts "Request failed: error"

If I set a breakpoint in the service code, I can see that the GetData function is being hit and appears to return successfully. I can also see in the firebug net console that the web service call is returning a status code of "200 OK", but the error handler callback is being hit instead of the success callback. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve this on my own. In case anyone is reading this and is curious, I changed the WCF service and web application so that they now both run via IIS instead of Visual Studio's web server.

So I now have

```
    http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetData?value=1
    http://localhost/WebApplication1/
```

I believe it was not working previously due to cross domain requests. Even though it was same domain, just different port numbers, I believe this still counts as cross domain?